# Can Polygon cross other Polygon on the surface?

Tags: shapely

I'm using Shapely (https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html)

I'm trying to get 'True' value for crosses method (https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#object.crosses) with two polygons, but I can't find suitable data.

A have two polygons, that have an interior that intersects, The interior doesn't contain each other.   I have trying two cases. In the first case intersection was a polygon(later I learned that it was not suitable, the dimension of a polygon is 2). In the second case intersection was a boundary of the interior of two polygons(dimension 1). But the method crosses return False again. So I started to think that this check is not at all possible for two polygons on the surface

Comment: Are you using geodatabase topology in ArcGIS Desktop or some other implementation of topology?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. There are a number of different definitions for "topology", so it's important to [Edit] your question to mention the GIS software in use and to provide one or more pictures/screenshots to explain your question.